# Corrupted parquet file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, sqoop, parquet

I have issue when trying to read parquet file with spark. The prquet file was created by sqoop:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:teradata://<ip>/Database=<DB> \
  --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
  --username <user> \
  --password <pass> \
  --table OFFERING \
  --target-dir /DWH/OFFERING \
  --as-parquetfile \
  --compress \
  --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
  -m 8
```

And file in hdfs directory looks correct:

```
[root@omm102 ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /DWH/OFFERING
Found 9 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs          0 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3630 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       4046 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3146 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3703 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00003
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3065 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00004
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       2972 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00005
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3405 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00006
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs       3091 2018-01-19 20:44 /DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00007
```

I've verified it with fstck also:

```
[root@omm101 ~]# hdfs fsck /DWH/OFFERING -files
Connecting to namenode via http://omm101.xxx:<port>/fsck?ugi=root&files=1&path=%2FDWH%2FOFFERING
FSCK started by root (auth:SIMPLE) from /<ip> for path /DWH/OFFERING at Mon Jan 22 15:40:35 GST 2018
/DWH/OFFERING <dir>
/DWH/OFFERING/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00000 3630 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00001 4046 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00002 3146 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00003 3703 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00004 3065 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00005 2972 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00006 3405 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/DWH/OFFERING/part-m-00007 3091 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    27058 B
 Total dirs:    1
 Total files:   9
 Total symlinks:                0
 Total blocks (validated):      8 (avg. block size 3382 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   8 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     3.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          5
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Mon Jan 22 15:40:35 GST 2018 in 2 milliseconds
```

But when I start spark-shell (2.2.1) and try to read it:

```
val offering = spark.read.parquet("/DWH/OFFERING/")
```

I got below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=hdfs://mycluster/DWH/ACCOUNT_PARTY/part-m-00000; isDirectory=false; length=60604112; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:493)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AugmentedIterableIterator$class.flatmap2combiner(RemainsIterator.scala:132)
        at scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector$ParVectorIterator.flatmap2combiner(ParVector.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$FlatMap.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:1072)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$FlatMap.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:1068)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:341)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:673)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask$class.sync(Tasks.scala:378)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.sync(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$class.executeAndWaitResult(Tasks.scala:426)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport.executeAndWaitResult(TaskSupport.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$ResultMapping.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:958)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$ResultMapping.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:953)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://mycluster/DWH/ACCOUNT_PARTY/part-m-00000 is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [48, 52, 53, 10]
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:476)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:445)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:421)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:499)
        ... 32 more
```

I'm not sure how to move forward.

Any help would be appreciate.

**EDIT1:**

To verify if this is not related to compression mechanism as suggested below I've checked below sqoop:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:teradata://<ip>/Database=<db> \
  --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
  --username <usr> \
  --password <paswd> \
  --table OFFERING \
  --target-dir /DWH/TST/OFFERING \
  --as-parquetfile \
  -m 8
```

ant then tried to read it again:

```
val offering = spark.read.parquet("/DWH/TST/OFFERING/")
```

but the reasult was the same

Comment: You might have to read the snappy compressed parquet differently

Comment: I don't think it is related to reading parquet. I've started spark-shell with:
`./spark-shell --conf spark.io.compression.codec=org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec` and, to be sure it is sett up, also executed `spark.conf.get("spark.io.compression.codec")` . When trying to execute: `val offering = spark.read.parquet("/DWH/OFFERING/")` I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

Accually answer here is quite simple. Below error is 100% true:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://mycluster/DWH/ACCOUNT_PARTY/part-m-00000 is not a Parquet file.
```

The files that was generated by sqoop has nothing to do with parquet. Those are simply CSV files. Even though I used `--as-parquetfile` flag, this means nothing because Hortonworks Connector for Teradata doesn't support Parquet. Funny thing is that sqoop doesn't create any WARN's during import with inappropriate flag.